# Doctrine Where 'IN' operator

Tags: doctrine

This portion of a Doctrine query is only returning results for "validated = 1".  How do I modify this query so it will also include results for validated = 3?  This is my first "IN".

```
        $query
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->in('m.validated', ':validated'))
            ->setParameter('validated', '1,3');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code instead,

```
$query
        ->andWhere('m.validated IN (:validated)')
        ->setParameter('validated', array('1','2'));
```

Or with the same code giving values in an array.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!